# Decision to add all predictive variables in Kaplan-Meier and Cox PH

Tags: r, survival, prediction, cox-model, kaplan-meier

In R's [`survival`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/survival.pdf) and [`rms`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rms/rms.pdf) packages, Kaplan-Meier (`Surv` and `survift`) and Cox Proportional Hazards (`cph`) are implemented.

I have been experimenting with these two by adding one-by-one the predictors I have in my dataset. These are not time-dependent meaning for one record, there is only one observation for these predictors which do not depend on a time basis.

The format for KM requires a `Surv` object to be made first before given to the `survfit` function for further processing.

```
fit      <- Surv(time,status)~X1+X2+X3+ ... +Xn
model.km <- survfit(fit)
```

`cph` also uses a similar way to create a Cox model.

```
model.cox = cph(fit, surv=TRUE, x=TRUE, y=TRUE)
```

---

Do I have to add all of my predictors in the dataset into the `Surv` in order to get a legitimate or wholesome representation of my data?

I always try to add each one at a time into the functions and look out for ones that will cause an error which I remove to go further the creation. If one of these predictors are not welcomed into `Surv`, `survfit` and `cph`, I instantly remove them from the creation and not the dataset. Is this method that I do correct?